# is there any where query in firestoreconnect react js redux firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore

i want to know if there is any where query that we can use 
i have this code

```
firestoreConnect(props => [
        {collection : 'projects' , where: [['user.uid', '==', props.authcheck.uid]]}
    ])
```

i have tried

> where

query and in where query i have used 'user.uid' as you can see in the code and i have used the authorId that is present uniquely in the projects collection . i want to see the specific projects added by specific author . 
after using where i am seeing this error

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined.

Comment: assuming you are creating docId inside the project collection based on userId,then you can access it ,by giving **doc**,param to that fireStoreConnect method

like this,
firestoreConnect(props => [
        {collection : 'projects' , doc: props.authcheck.uid}
    ])